# What is a word for someone who sees themself as ‘unlovable’?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, emotions

I’m doing some character work and I was wondering if anyone could find a word that means *‘someone who feels unlovable’* or *‘believes themself unworthy of having their love returned’*.

I'm looking for something a little more targeted than just *‘self-deprecating’* as I don’t feel like that really fits, and a little more concise than just *‘feels unworthy of love.’*

For context, this character has been in love with someone since childhood but has given up on pursuing his feelings because he feels he is not worthy of her love. I wouldn’t necessarily call it *‘low self-esteem’* since it’s just in this situation, but I could accept that as an answer :)

Looking for adjectives, but I’m open to anything.

Comment: Is it relevant if this self-assessment is too harsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the word *loveworthy*; and its counterpart ***unloveworthy*** is existent also, rather as a neologism. The *un-* prefix is a productive prefix in English; and in this case, it is prefixed to an adjective to express a negative sense.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/110628#eid38919853)* defines *loveworthy* as below:

> Worthy of being loved. Also as *n.*: a person who is worthy of love.

*Loveworthy* is used both as a noun and an adjective, but mainly as an adjective. *OED* provides a noun example of *loveworthy* as *the loveworthy*:

> Well, bless you both. Give our loves to the love-worthy. 
> <sub>1940     A. Huxley *Let.* 5 Jan. (1969) 449</sub>

The same definition can be applied to *unloveworthy* by changing worthy to unworthy. *Unloveworthy* can have the connotations of having a self-image of unloveworthiness within the right context, with a more sentimental approach, where *unlovable* lacks that. *Unlovable* is more like someone who is incapable of being loved, undesirable or lacking attractive qualities etc., and it can be used for things other than people also.

Here is a relevant example I've found with *unloveworthy*:

> He essentially feels unloveworthy and responds to this belief with lonely self-sufficiency. He makes a virtue out of being stoically "independent" or dependent only on himself. 
> <sub>[*mtlawleycounselling.com.au*](https://www.mtlawleycounselling.com.au/fear-of-rejection.html)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Low self-esteem is good, as well as low self-worth, insecure, inferiority complex, and lacking respect.

Answer (score 2):

### Self-loathing

This is someone who feels they are not good enough, and that they are unworthy. This often involves self-hatred and very low self-esteem.

Comment: I'd say that self-loathing is a step further than seeing yourself as unlovable. Certainly in the same direction though.